# Easiest to use, lightweight, platform independent graphing library for C++

Tags: c++, graphing, platform-independent

What is the simplest to use c++ library that graphs functions like matlab and octave do? I have looked over several and have found similar major problems with all of them: i cannot compile an empty program that only has

```
#include <iostream>

#include "header_to_include.h"

int main(){

   return 0;
}
```

i have found koolplot, some wxwidget stuff, sdl_graph, gnuplot++, and something with Qt. ive looked at some of the ones on the list [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492893/graph-drawing-c-library), but some are for other languages while others use installers or depended on other programs. When I got files extracted and tried compiling my simple code or given example code from within the download, codeblocks always complains about missing headers or variables or some other things.

i would use gnuplot, except i dont want to create gnuplot files from my cpp files, even if its through a pipe. i want to be able to graph straight from the program.

is there nothing that is simply a handful of files in a zip that can be extracted and used in moments rather than having to figure out which files to include, installing/downloading other major libraries, etc?

edit:

for example, i found http://sdl-grapher.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ and downloaded the files. i already have sdl, so i copied sdlgraph.h into the includes folder and left a copy in the same directory as example.c. when i compile, i find that for some reason, `#include <sdlgraph.h>` doesnt work. also the `int main()` has no arguments despite being a SDL program. after fixing that up, i get `undefined reference` to 15 different functions that i can clearly see in the `sdlgraph.h` file such as `init_graph` and `draw_grid`

Comment: Thing is, graph plotting is *hard*. And you need some graphics backend to render the output.

Comment: if you are planning to work in C++, better start some learning and get used to having to download and install libraries. That's just the way it works, there is no single button thet gets you everything you want with one click.

Comment: i know, but i expect to at least be able to compile an empty program. i cant really proceed if i cant so much as use the libraries

Comment: Well, if you can't "compile an empty program", you'll need to be more specific about what you tried and the error messages you got. Otherwise nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: ok. give me a moment to update the post

Comment: Yo're probably forgetting to link an SDL library, or you are not adding the C files from the library in your project/makefile.

Answer (score 0):

About your errors:
Since you're very new to C++ I'll explain your `undefined reference` errors.

In C++ you can declare a function like this:

```
void foo();
```

However, since it's declared, it doesn't main it's defined. Definitions can exist in C++ source file, libraries but also headers.

Defining the previous example:

```
void foo() {
    std::cout << "void foo() has been called." << std::endl;
}
```

The error you get means that those functions just aren't defined.
I quess you have to link your application with the SDL libraries.

For more info see:
http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/SDL:Tutorials:Setup

For more info about dynamic and static linking see:
http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/a1-static-and-dynamic-libraries/

Hope it helps!